# Does this non-negative function without stationary points have only descend directions close to a constraint set?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, constraints, stationary-point

Suppose $P: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} $ is differentiable map, with $P(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}$ and $P(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}^c$. Further, suppose $P$ has **no stationary points** in $\mathcal{X}^c$, i.e. $\nabla P(x) \not= 0 \ \forall x \in \mathcal{X}$.

My Intuition is that $P$ eventually has a descent direction when we approach $\partial \mathcal{X}$ from $\mathcal{X}^c$. I need to make this more precise! For example, can we show that

$$ \forall x \in \partial \mathcal{X} ~ \exists \varepsilon >0 : \forall y \in \mathcal{X}^c ~ ||x-y||<\varepsilon \Rightarrow \nabla P(y)^T(x-y)<0 ?$$

Here is what I thought of:
For $x\in \partial \mathcal{X}$ and $y \in \mathcal{X}^c$ Taylor tells us that
$$0 = P(y) + \nabla_xP(y)^\top(x-y) + o(||x-y||). $$
So this is almost what I need. However, I don't see that I can conclude here using $P(y) > 0$ that
$$ \nabla_xP(y)^\top(x-y) < 0 $$
for $y$ close to $x$. Because, although $0 \approx P(y) + \nabla_xP(y)^\top(x-y)$, we also have that $P$ and all differentials decay to zero as we approach the boundary. I also thought about MVT, but this doesn't seam to help since I need to keep my $y$ (as above) flexible.

It would be helpful if someone could point out whether this is obvious or whether I need additional assumptions. Thank You! You may assume $\mathcal{X}$ to be compact.

Comment: I welcome suggestions to improve the title.